# SSL implementation over limited AT Commands (ESP32, AI Thinker A9G)

Tags: c++, ssl, https, esp32

I'm working on a project on the ESP32 connected to an AI Thinker A9G through serial. Right now I'm using the AT commands the A9G is shipped with. I have to connect to a Google App Engine endpoint over https, but there is no AT command support for SSL on the A9G.

Is there a way to wrap the A9G at commands in a c++ ssl library on the ESP?

If so, what ssl library would you recommend?

It seems like a giant project, and I'm thinking about changing GPS/GPRS module to something with better SSL support.

Comment: Hi Oscar, any chance you can share how managed to get it to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AT commands are a rather limited interface for talking to Internet. If they work, it's a great shortcut. If they don't, well, they don't.

The ESP32 can support a ppp dialup stack natively, talk to Internet, do HTTPS requests etc. Just use the modem as a regular dumb old modem, a terminal to establish a data connection.

Comment: You're a total f***ing lifesaver. There is almost no documentation on interfacing with the modem on the A9G, but it seems pretty standardised. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm facing a similar issue. Did you use any particular library?

Comment: I don’t remember if I ever got it to work with the A9G, we did a custom board instead. I would probably stay away from the AT commands for everything but changing settings… reading the gps signal in one stream and internet communication through another… if possible create your own board, you can skip a lot of tedious code if you do so…

Comment: I was stuck trying to make the AT commands work, so your advice is great. Thanks Oscar!